# How to resolve "ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' while installing pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Trying to install pip on a ubuntu system without root acccess fails as as shown below.

```
tcsh-334: wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
--2016-10-23 20:42:13--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
Resolving bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)... 151.101.xx.175
Connecting to bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)|151.101.xx.175|:443...    connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1524722 (1.5M) [text/x-python]
Saving to: `get-pip.py'

100%[=================>] 1,524,722   1.70M/s   in 0.9s    

2016-10-23 20:42:15 (1.70 MB/s) - `get-pip.py' saved [1524722/1524722]
```

OK now lets try to run it....Here is where the error occurs.

```
tcsh-335: python get-pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 19177, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpyi0bm3ms/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpyi0bm3ms/pip.zip/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpyi0bm3ms/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpyi0bm3ms/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpyi0bm3ms/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpyi0bm3ms/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

here's the version of python I just successfully installed (with --prefix to a user-specified place.)

```
tcsh-336: which python
/volume/diags/python/bin/python

tcsh-337: python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

So, What is my problem? ... Or how do I resolve this?

Comment: have you try `python get-pip.py --user`? this post may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/363300/how-to-install-pip-python-to-user-without-root-access

Comment: I get the exact same thing.  Problem is I only have access to Python 2.7, 3.2 and the version I just installed, 3.5.  When I try to use pip to upgrade anything, it fails with the message "/homes/<me>/.local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py:80: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):